# changing number of different columns on notepad++

Tags: numbers, notepad++

example text like this :

> abcde abcde abcde 01 abcde abcde abcde 01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi 01 efghiefghiefghiefghi 01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   abcde abcde abcde 01 abcde abcde abcde 01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi 01 efghiefghiefghiefghi 01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   abcde abcde abcde 01 abcde abcde abcde 01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi 01 efghiefghiefghiefghi 01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   ...
>   ...`

and i need to be like this :

> abcde abcde abcde 01 abcde abcde abcde 01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi 01 efghiefghiefghiefghi 01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   abcde abcde abcde 02 abcde abcde abcde 02
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi 02 efghiefghiefghiefghi 02
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 02 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 02
>   abcde abcde abcde 03 abcde abcde abcde 03
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi 03 efghiefghiefghiefghi 03
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 03 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 03
>   ...
>   ...`

i want just change the numbers of each lines

what i try so far is make the number on same column  like this :

> abcde abcde abcde ##########01 abcde abcde abcde #01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi #####01 efghiefghiefghiefghi #01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   abcde abcde abcde ##########01 abcde abcde abcde #01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi #####01 efghiefghiefghiefghi #01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   abcde abcde abcde ##########01 abcde abcde abcde #01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi #####01 efghiefghiefghiefghi #01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01

then i use column editor>number to insert to change the numbers

> abcde abcde abcde ##########01 abcde abcde abcde #01
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi #####01 efghiefghiefghiefghi #01
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 01
>   abcde abcde abcde ##########02 abcde abcde abcde #02
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi #####02 efghiefghiefghiefghi #02
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 02 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 02
>   abcde abcde abcde ##########03 abcde abcde abcde #03
>   efghi efghi efghiefghiefghi #####03 efghiefghiefghiefghi #03
>   jklmnjklmn jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 03 jklmnjklmnjklmnjklmn 03

the i delete the hashtags using find and replace.

so, just change the numbers. is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not clear what want, what are the rules to change to numbers? What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: i want to change the numbers like the example.

Comment: Why `01` sometimes stays the same, sometimes becomes `02` or `03` ?

Comment: @Toto 3 lines of 01 is what i want to change to 3 lines 02, next 3 lines 03, next 3 lines 04, etc...